# Tor mobile browesr fingerprint

Tags: fingerprinting, mobile

The desktop version of Tor is always preferred over the mobile version.

Question: what does mobile app Tor leak about the user that the desktop doesn't leak?

For example, one thing I noticed is lack of letter-boxing, so websites will more likely detect mobile screen resolution.